# Vue i18n object syntax with parameter inside quotation marks

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm using Vuei18n, and, reading from https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#list-formatting, I discovered I could use the object syntax. What I would like to achieve is to get a translation with a parameter that will be inserted dinamically:

```
"object": {
    "ciao '{0}'": "HALLO '{0}'"
}
```

Usage: `i18n.global.t('object.' + "ciao '{0}'", param)`

Expectation: "ciao 'Bob'"

Result: it doesn't translate at all.

The problem is in those single quotation marks, if I would remove them, it would work.

So how could I keep the single quotation marks?

Comment: You want to have a dynamic key here? Like `ciao 'bob'`? Could you please tell us what you expect at the end?

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting Otherwise, this one is more funky/advanced but quite powerful too: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage

Comment: But maybe a quick solution would be to use ` "ciao": "HALLO \'{0}\'"` and run it like `$t('ciao', { 0: 'bob' })`.

Comment: @kissu yes, I woould like to have "ciao 'bob'", but it doesn't translate at all

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the quotation marks also on the key side "ciao '{0}'"

Comment: This syntax is intended to be used with message tokens that are named similarly to JS dot notation like `foo.bar`, i.e. there shouldn't be chars like `'` in key names. I'd expect that what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: You can have pretty much anything on the right side (the value). You can also call a dynamic key with `$t(myVar)` but I can't the point of having a dynamic key tho. If you have `ciaoUsername`, you can still say `hallo bob` or `hallo patrick`. There is no point into having a `ciaoBob` and `ciaoPatrick` really. What's your need based-on?

Comment: I receive the keys from a service. So I would just translate the keys at runtime:

i18n.global.t('object.' + key, param)